# Interpreting r.regression.multi

Tags: grass-gis, regression, correlation, multiple, cross-validation

I cannot find a source that explains how to interpret the output of [r.regression.multi](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.regression.multi.html). Can someone explain what the different lines mean; specifically how do I see if the results are significant?

```
X=precipitation and temperature
y=bumblebee occurrence

---
n=43621
Rsq=0.148596
Rsqadj=0.148556
RMSE=0.126423
MAE=0.102174
F=3806.322579
b0=0.670497
AIC=-180420.870163
AICc=-180420.870163
BIC=-180394.820282

--

predictor1=rast_645a2c86c33e256
b1=-0.000001
Rsq1=0.000008
F1=0.406184
AIC1=-180422.463954
AICc1=-180422.463954
BIC1=-180415.780660

--

predictor2=rast_645a2c86c359757
b2=-0.028587
Rsq2=0.148058
F2=7585.114031
AIC2=-173429.095957
AICc2=-173429.095957
BIC2=-173422.412663
```

[image: r.regression.multi]

(properties table: range from red -0.0772 to blue 0.6045)

Comment: Since this is moving into the realm of statistics, you might consider to take your question to:  [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

- Rsq= unadjusted r2
- Rsqadj = adjusted r2
- RMSE = root-mean-square error
- MAE = mean absolute error
- F = not certain; likey f-statistics
- b0= intercept
- AIC = Akaike information criterion
- AICc= Akaike information criterion corrected for sample size
- BIC=  Bayesian information criterion

r2 tells you how well your model explains the observed data (the higher, the better). AIC tells you how the model predicts with new data (the **lower**, the better; see also [r2 vs AIC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140965/when-aic-and-adjusted-r2-lead-to-different-conclusions)).

Your result indicates that your model explains 15% of the variation in bumblebee occurrences, with predictor 2 (temperature) being the stronger predictor.  You may want to run the model only with predictor 2.

As for significance - r.regression multi is designed to handle large datasets where significance levels are unreliable indicators - with large samples, even small effects are significant. This consideration applies to your dataset as well. Thus, no significance levels are provided.